# System tool which is ArcPy/Python script will not run and error is blank using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.4, windows-10

When I try and run any script tools from ArcToolbox, the red X icon shows up next to the input features line, but there is no error when I hover over the X. If I proceed with the tool and click OK, I get a blank error message with the yellow exclamation point error (see screen capture below). I have tried multiple script tools and am having the same error with each. An example tool that is not working is "Generate Points Along Lines". The input features are shapefiles with projected coordinate systems.

I am running ArcMap 10.4.1 (Basic) on Windows 10 Pro.

I have no experience with Python, but based on some reading I have done online, I am wondering if this error from the Generate Points Along Lines tool is Python related.

[image: error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps something was recently installed, such as Esri Business Analyst or a different version of Python on the system.  If so, an important detail to note will be if this worked before the install of these products.  You could open the Python window in ArcGIS and type something simple like "`import os`" to see if it immediately crashes. I would recommend a reinstall as that helped in a similar situation for me.

Comment: I uninstalled and reinstalled this morning and the problem is solved. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

My problem like this was solved by also reinstalling background Geoprocessing. Now ArcMap and also ArcCatalog can run Python scripts again.

Answer (score 0):

As @Hornbydd said in a comment (which has been removed by a moderator):

> ... have found that the University I work within sometimes simply
> don't install the python component when they install ArcGIS of peoples
> workstations. They install everything else like extensions. It's as if
> they have deliberately left it off as they provide separate python
> installs for other department needs. Seems less of an issue now but it
> may have been down to the initial installation missing the ArcGIS
> compatible install of Python ...